# why to implement callbacks and event handler attachment using javascript closures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

What value do we get by using closures in JavaScript for implementing callbacks and and event handler attachment . I know jQuery uses this pattern extensively but want to understand why ?

Comment: What do you see as the option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a closure as a callback gives you access to the scope which it is defined within. It also helps keep your namespace clean. Other libraries allow you to bind object methods as event handlers, giving the event access to the object, which is a pretty elegant alternative solution. For instance, maybe something like this:

```
// an object definition
var Accordion = function () {
   this.clickCounter = 0;
};
Accordion.prototype.click = function () {
   this.clickCounter += 1;
   alert( this.clickCounter );
};

// create object
var myAccordion = new Accordion();

// function to bind DOM element events to javascript object methods
function methodBind ( element, eventType, myObject, myMethod ) {
   $( element ).bind( eventType, function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      myObject[myMethod ].call(myObject);
   } );
}

// bind buttons on an element to activate a correlating object method
$( '.Accordion' ).find( '.button' ).each( function() {
   methodBind( this, 'click', myAccordion, 'click' );
} );
```

Although my implementation also uses closures haha.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you might endup in what Esailija describes, but you might also save some kittens. Event handlers in closures give you access to local scope. So instead of

```
var uselessMap = {};

function myListener(e) {
    alert(uselessMap[e.target.id].foo);    
}

items.forEach(function(item) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerText = item.name;
    el.id = item.id;
    el.addEventListener('click', myListener, false);
})
```

You only need this:

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerText = item.name;
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert(item.foo);
    }, false);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really understand what you need.
Closures is not jQuery system, it's the main core or Javascript.

The thing is Javascript is a language event based. While you make an ajax call, your javascript will continue running and not stopping expecting the result. So you need to have a callback method to be able to do something once it's done.

I know it may be frustrating when coming from a blocking language like PHP where you call a function and the line below is executed when the action is done. But it's the Javascript philosophy. Do not wait while you can do other thing, just be able to pop when this or this event is called.

Typically, for events like click/change on input/submit a form etc, you cannot wait and block all your code until some action popped out. So attach a listener to each event you want to ear about and continue your way.

Comment: I know what you are saying is that javascript is event based and I also know that closures are a part of vanilla javascript . I am basically asking the value of closures in implementing callbacks . for example what value do we get by retaining the environment of the already finished execution context while implementing callbacks .

Comment: That's the scope system. If you are in an object when defining a callback, without this system, you will not be able to come back to your object without defining an ugly global variable regrouping all instances.